# Is it possible to change the localStorage file name where i saved data?

Tags: javascript

I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this,
Basically, I am creating a google chrome extension with the objective of saving data from forms in the localStorage folder, so far, so good, it's all working fine and stuff, my question is, is it possible to change the name of the file where I will save my data?

Let's say I am creating a new account in google, and I want to save the data that i entered so far, I click in the extension icon, save the data and then in localStorage, the file name where my data is stored is "https_accounts.google.com_0.localstorage", is it possible to change something in my js code that appends (for example the date and time when that especific data was saved) to the file name, making it "22-9-16_16:40_https_accounts.google.com_0.localstorage"?

Thank you for reading and I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out, sorry if I messed up everything while writing this or if I have the solution right in front of my eyes, but I really don't know if it's possible, and, if it is, how to do it. 
Again, Thank you very much, have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

How the browser records data for localstorage is an implementation detail. It is not exposed to JavaScript in a webpage at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and for answering to my question, cheers